# nvcc -V not found with CUDA installed

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

I am running the docker image `nvidia/cuda:11.2.2-base-ubuntu20.04`. When I run the command `nvidia-smi`, looks like CUDA is already installed as it prints:

```
Fri Apr 30 11:00:48 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.36.06    Driver Version: 450.36.06    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P5000        On   | 00000000:00:05.0 Off |                  Off |
| 26%   38C    P8     6W / 180W |      1MiB / 16278MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, the command `nvcc -V` or `nvcc --version` shows `command not found`. In addition, if I try to install `cuda-toolkit` via `apt-get install cuda-toolkit`, it end up installing `CUDA 10.0`, which triggers a mismatch between versions. Thus, I was wondering how could I find nvcc or install the proper CUDA (Which I suppose is `CUDA 11`)

Comment: Did you add the ...cuda/bin and ...cuda/lib to the beginning of your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH like the Nvidia installation instr say?  nvcc is just tucked away in the bin directory under your cuda install location.

Comment: For some reason I cannot find it in /usr/loca/cuda or /usr/local/cuda-11-1/. Running ls yields the following folders: …/cuda-11.2/compat/  …/cuda-11.2/lib64/  .../cuda-11.2/targets/ and inside none of them has a "bin" file. I thought that was included in the docker image. Manual installation of CUDA leads to: Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch.